# Pulling data from two tables (for a 'related products' query) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull data from two tables for a 'related products' widget.
I've tried all the JOINS and UNIONS I can and still get nothing.

The first table (`productdocs`) stores documents. The second (`prodrelated`) shows when a product is related to a document:

- **productdocs**

  - `pdid` (unique ID for the document)
  - `pdname` (name of the uploaded document)
- **prodrelated**

  - `prprodid` (the ID for the PRODUCT)
  - `pritemid` (the ID for the document)

I am trying to output the `productdocs.pdname` for any documents that match up with the product's id.  In otherwords, show the pdname when:

```
WHERE productdocs.pdid = prodrelated.pritemid
```

I would post my SQL code, but none of it has worked, so I think it would be pointless. I hope I explained this correctly given my frazzled brain - Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have described seems like a pretty simple join.  Why don't you post sample data and the SQL you have tried?

Comment: Even if your code doesn't work, it's better to show what you have tried.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `INNER JOIN` for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT pd.pdid, pd.pdname
FROM   productdocs pd JOIN prodrelated pr ON pd.pdid = pr.pritemid
WHERE  pd.prprodid = <any_id>;
```

If you don't want to filter out any records, you can get rid of `WHERE` clause and it will output all the records.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) MySQL's documentation for `JOIN`.

Comment: I tried to +1 your answer but maybe i don't have enough 'reputation'?  It went 'negative 1' instead and I don't know how to change it!!!

Comment: I hope everyone will check out Darshan's answer and agree with me that it works and please give it a +1 vote!!!   The system is not letting me vote it positive - I am SO SORRY DARSHAN! YOU ROCK!

Comment: That's absolutely fine mate, don't worry. I was just wondering why it got downvoted, whether it was not correct etc?

Comment: @BlueDaNoob - You should now have enough rep to [up vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Did it say something like your vote was locked unless the question was edited? That has happened to me before. I made a small edit so you should now be able to up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Wow you guys are fast - thank you so much.

Darshan - thank you above all, I was able to make a few mods to what you wrote and it worked great.   I tried to +1 your answer but maybe I don't have enough 'reputation'? Here is what I got working, thanks to you:

```
SELECT pd.pdid, pd.pdname
FROM productdocs pd 
        JOIN prodrelated pr 
        ON pd.pdid = pr.pritemid
WHERE pr.prprodid = '#url.prodid#'
```

In the future I will try to post some code example, but on this one I honestly tried at least 7 different queries so I had no idea which to post!

Comment: Never, never use raw client supplied variables in SQL as it puts the database at risk for [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html) is your friend :-)

Comment: Thanks, Leigh!  This is all in the Admin section behind a log-in; not public-facing.  Still a concern in that situation?

Comment: When it comes to web apps, trust nothing ;-) Plus, the primary purpose of cfqueryparam is really to improve query performance (and who doesn't want that?).  Protection against sql injection is just a nice benefit. Bottom line, unless you have a really, really good reason *not* to - always use cfqueryparam :-)

Comment: Shall do!  Thanks for explaining that, Leigh.